# Ubuntu Live CD customization with automated install

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, live-cd, customization, alternative

I am trying to customize an installation CD for Ubuntu 12.04 but I'm having some issues.  I've used Ubuntu Builder and Ubuntu Customization Kit (UCK) and successfully updated packages and added packages to the CD/DVD itself, but I cannot find a way to automate the install with the Live CD.

I've looked into using the Alternative CD, but neither of the above programs will load it as they are looking for the Live CD architecture.  From the documentation for Alternative CD customization, it looks like I can specify packages to be downloaded during install, but I would like to have them included in the CD/DVD in case the user doesn't have internet access and also it would lead to a faster install.

I've tried to add a preseed file to the LiveCD, but the installer doesn't seem to take it.  Could this be user error, or does the Live CD installer reject a preseed file?  I added a preseed file to /cdrom/preseed/preseed.cfg (same area as ubuntu.seed) and used the following in the /isolinux/txt.cfg file:

```
default live-install
label live
  menu label ^Try Ubuntu without installing
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed preseed/file=/cdrom/preseed/preseed.cfg boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --
label live-install
  menu label ^Install Ubuntu
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed preseed/file=/cdrom/preseed/preseed.cfg boot=casper only-ubiquity initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --
```

I've also tried editing the ubuntu.seed file to add some information to it, it seems to take some of the info (location and some user info, but not the password), but it still requires the user to go through the install screens.

Preferably I would like to have the user boot up the CD, click the 'Install Ubuntu' button, and have the preseed file fill in the questions (location, user info, partitioning, etc.) without having to click through them.  I would also like to either edit the text below the Try or Install buttons to warn of an automated install that will wipe the system, or better yet, have a popup that warns the user of loss of data.

Is this possible, or can I use the Alternative CD and add packages to the installation disk to have an offline install?

Answer (score 0):

There is a method of creating a live CD, customized on [Help.Ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MakeALiveCD/DVD/BootableFlashFromHarddiskInstall)